# How to get formatted html code from edited text in summernote

Tags: javascript, html, summernote

I am using summernote text editor. I want to get html formatted of text edited in editor. In summernote editor toolbar having a code view button. when click on the button we can see the html code of edited text. Now, I want html code to get as string or stored in variable. How it possible?

Please help me.

reference : github code is https://github.com/summernote/summernote

Comment: you get html code in variable after post method no require to any function or any implementation

Comment: when i am using this code   <div class="container">

    <div id="summernote" class="summernote"><p>Hello World</p></div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
  <script>
function myFunction() {

var MyDiv2 = document.getElementById('summernote');
    alert(MyDiv2.innerHTML);
}
</script> It not showing updated code

Comment: my problem is solved. pls check the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines to index.html

```
<div class="container">
<div id="summernote" class="summernote"><p>Hello World</p></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var MyDiv2 = document.getElementsByClassName('note-editable');
    m = MyDiv2[0];
    alert(m.innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have method `summernote` with argument `'code'` for this.

Example:

```
<div class="summernote"></div>
<script>
    $('.summernote').summernote();
</script>
```

Then Type something in field created from div and type in console:

```
$('.summernote').summernote('code')
```

You should see the same result as in example in @john answer